# How to fix the error 'AttributeError: module 'board' has no attribute 'SCK'' I am using raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am using a modul max31865 and a pt100 sensor to measure the temperature but, I have a problem when i run the program,because appears this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/eduardo/videos/temperature.py", line 5, in <module>
    spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
AttributeError: module 'board' has no attribute 'SCLK'
```

I don't know what the problem is.

```
import board
import busio
import digitalio
import adafruit_max31865

spi = busio.SPI(board.SCLK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)  # Chip select of the MAX31865 board.
sensor = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(spi, cs, wires=3)

print('Temperature: {0:0.3f}C'.format(sensor.temperature))
print('Resistance: {0:0.3f} Ohms'.format(sensor.resistance))`enter code here`
```

I expect to read the temperature

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Are you very sure that should not be `board.SCLK`? Your code seems to be quite close to [this example](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/installing-circuitpython-on-raspberry-pi) and that is how the constant is spelled there.

Comment: Or SCL seems to be one option also in that site.

Comment: i change it, but the problem is the same

Comment: Is it *exactly* the same or do you get a different error on the same line? Or maybe the same error on a different line? I would expect the sample code to be correct.

Comment: Edit your question to show the code as it now is that is giving the error.

Comment: i change it from SCL to SCLK

Comment: But the traceback in your question still reports a problem with `board.SCK` so you haven't updated your question accurately to show the new error message.

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me

```
sudo pip3 install --force-reinstall adafruit-blinka
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled I2C interface in `raspi-config`?